# Material design (Polymer) with jQuery in PhoneGap application

Tags: jquery, cordova, material-design

Is it possible to use material design (Polymer) with jQuery in a PhoneGap application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible of course. You can decide weather using Jquery, Angular or whatever.
Check this example
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/

Comment: which one is better.polymer or materializecss

Answer (score 0):

Simple Material Design project based on reactjs is available on github [here](https://github.com/michalradziwon/social-search-hybrid-client/tree/pre-hackhaton). It is very easy it run, so just clone the repo and play with that...